# Updating a QtableWidget with a connect

Tags: c++, qt

I stumble into a problem that I'm a little puzzled by it.

On the constructor of this widget I call a function `fillQualityReport()` which fills the table:

```
RepackProcess::RepackProcess(DataBase *d, QPrinter *p, QWidget *parent) : QMdiSubWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::RepackProcess)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  data=d;
  printer=p;
  loadDropDownMenus();
  fillQualityReport();
  connect(ui->quality,SIGNAL(cellChanged(int,int)),this,SLOT(updateTotalLosses()));
}
```

Here is the function to fill up the quality report:

```
void RepackProcess::fillQualityReport()
{
  int commodity;
  QSqlQuery query, defects;
  query.prepare("select * from commodity where (name=:name)"); // Looking for the commodity id
  query.bindValue(":name",ui->Commodity->currentText());
  query.exec();
  query.next();
  commodity=query.value(0).toInt();
  query.prepare("select * from quality where (id_commodity=:commodity)");
  query.bindValue(":commodity",commodity);
  query.exec();
  query.next();
  query.last();
  totalQualityDefects = query.at()<0 ? 0 : query.at()+1;
  ui->quality->setColumnCount(2);       // Setting the column and row counts for the table
  ui->quality->setRowCount(totalQualityDefects);
  ui->quality->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Defect;Percent").split(";"));
  ui->quality->setColumnWidth(0,60);
  ui->quality->setColumnWidth(1,60);
  query.first();      // Movind the pointer of the query back to before the first record
  query.previous();
  int currentRow=0;
  while (query.next()) {    // Filling the table with the defect names
      defects.prepare("select name from defects where (id=:id)");
      defects.bindValue(":id",query.value(2).toInt());
      defects.exec();
      defects.next();
      ui->quality->setItem(currentRow,0,new QTableWidgetItem(defects.value(0).toString()));
      ui->quality->setItem(currentRow,1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(0.00,'f',2)));
      ui->quality->item(currentRow,1)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignVCenter);
      currentRow++;
    }
}
```

and here the one to update the table when there are changes on the quality report:

```
void RepackProcess::updateTotalLosses()
{
  totalLoss=0;
  QSqlQuery query;
  query.prepare("select * from commodity where name=:name");
  query.bindValue(":name",commodityLabel);
  query.exec();
  query.next();
  int commodityId=query.value(0).toInt();
  for(int x=0; x<totalQualityDefects;x++)
    {
      qDebug()<<x;
      QString defect=ui->quality->item(x,0)->text();
      qDebug()<<defect;
      query.prepare("select * from defects where name=:name");
      query.bindValue(":name",defect);
      query.exec();
      query.next();
      int defectId = query.value(0).toInt();
      query.prepare("select * from quality where (id_commodity=:commodity and id_defects=:defects)");
      query.bindValue(":commodity",commodityId);
      query.bindValue(":defects",defectId);
      query.exec();
      query.next();
      qDebug()<<query.lastError();
      if(ui->quality->item(x,1)->text().toFloat()<query.value(3).toFloat())
        {
          totalLoss += ui->quality->item(x,1)->text().toFloat() * query.value(4).toFloat();
        }
      else if(ui->quality->item(x,1)->text().toFloat()<query.value(5).toFloat())
        {
          totalLoss += ui->quality->item(x,1)->text().toFloat() * query.value(6).toFloat();
        }
      else
        {
          totalLoss += ui->quality->item(x,1)->text().toFloat() * query.value(8).toFloat();
        }
    }
  ui->totalLoss->setText(QString::number(totalLoss,'f',2));
}
```

My problem is the following, with the connect function on the constructor I get an error when filling up the table. It seems to me that the program is calling the update function before the table is fully populated and the program crashes on the second line of the table. As the table is being filled up, the connect notice a change on the data and triggers the update, which knows the number of lines that are in the table

If I take the connect out and replace with a button for update works with no problem. I was looking at all the signals from the table view and could not find one that only triggers when data has been accessed from the screen.

Sorry for the long post, but you always ask for code.

```
#ifndef REPACKPROCESS_H
#define REPACKPROCESS_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMdiSubWindow>
#include <QPrinter>

#include "database.h"

namespace Ui {
  class RepackProcess;
}

class RepackProcess : public QMdiSubWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit RepackProcess(DataBase *d, QPrinter *p, QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~RepackProcess();

  void fillQualityReport(void);  // This function will resize and change the quality table for imput
  void loadDropDownMenus(void); // This function reads the tables and adds the selection to the drop down.

  void updateRepackCost(void);  // This function updates the costs table when parameters are changed
  void updateSheetCalculation(void); // This function updates all the calculations of the sheet


private slots:
  void on_Commodity_activated(const QString &arg1);
  void on_Warehouse_activated(const QString &arg1);
  void on_Format_activated(const QString &arg1);
  void on_totalCases_valueChanged(int arg1);
  void updateTotalLosses(int col, int row);  // This function updates the estimated total loses

  void on_updateLoss_clicked();

private:
  Ui::RepackProcess *ui;
  DataBase *data;
  QPrinter *printer;

  QSqlRelationalTableModel *costsModel;

  QString countryLabel, commodityLabel, modeLabel, warehouseLabel, formatLabel;

  int totalCases;  // This is the total number of cases that started the process
  float totalLoss; // Thi is the percentage of total loses in the process.
  int totalQualityDefects; // This is the number of defect that are showing on the quality report.

};

#endif // REPACKPROCESS_H
```

Comment: what is your qt version?

Comment: change `void updateTotalLosses()`  to `void updateTotalLosses(int, int)`

Comment: qt version 5.9.1. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: also try: `connect(ui->quality, &QTableWidget::cellChanged ,this, &RepackProcess::updateTotalLosses);`

Comment: Suggestion did not work, crashed at the same point, talking about your firs suggestion

Comment: @eyllanesc just making sure, that connect does not have SIGNAL and SLOT. Is that correct?

Comment: read this: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: No, luck with the second suggestion. Crashed at the same pleace

Comment: You have to add the parameters to the declaration and the implementation of the method.

Comment: I did. here is what it looks like now: RepackProcess::updateTotalLosses(int col, int row)

Comment: I did not mean for the second option but for the first option. Study the previous link.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing i did when implemented the first option

Comment: please, show the header file of RepackProcess class

Comment: Added to the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right with this statement:

> It seems to me that the program is calling the update function before
>   the table is fully

Since you are changed a cell:
 `connect(ui->quality,SIGNAL(cellChanged(int,int)),this,SLOT(updateTotalLosses()));` 
is used and thus `updateTotalLosses()` is called.

To fix it prevent itself from signalling using:

```
ui->quality->blockSignals(true);
ui->quality->blockSignals(false);
```

So you need to do something like this:

```
fillQualityReport()
{
    ui->quality->blockSignals(true);
    ... // your code
    ui->quality->blockSignals(false);
}
```

and

```
updateTotalLosses()
{
    ui->quality->blockSignals(true);
    ... // your code
    ui->quality->blockSignals(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you note, i will try for my self when i have a chance. But, could i use those commands on the constructor? as to block the signals there while the tables are being constructed?

Comment: Looking at it again I may be wrong since your connect is after your fillQualityRepory.  I don't think you need it in the constructor. Just try putting it in the update method.

Comment: Or try both since it doesn't hurt. If it fails let me know.